# Pass values from page to user control using Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, api

I have user control in modal popup and one button on .aspx page.
on button click I have to pass Id from aspx page to user control.
I am working on Ajax environment....any one pls help me

Comment: Post some code, that will allow us to get a better picture of the problem you are trying to solve. Without context there is little we can deduce from your question and are left to guess. @karan :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using bootstrap as well: 
Create **user control** as Popup box, example UcPopUp.ascx. Add function to set parameters/ object passed from aspx page.

```
public void SetId (string id) {
 TbId.Text = id;
}
```

Create javascript file, ex. sample.js

```
 var sample = {
   openModal: function() {
   $('#ucpopup').show()
   }
 }
```

In aspx page include javascript above, add bootsrap modal, put your ascx file in modal body. In this example I am using Update Panel

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" Id="ScrMng"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <uc:UcPopUp ID="PopUp" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1"/>
    </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

In aspx code in the button_click() event, send parameters/ object to user control. Call script manager to execute the javascript.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 UcPopUp.SetId(TbIdAspx.Text)
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "none", "<script>sample.openModal()</script>", false);
}
```

Hope it's help.